# Connection to Oracle database is very slow, 20-30 seconds to open

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

When opening our VB application and it's pointing to an Oracle database, it takes 20-30 seconds for it to open. Oracle 11.2 is installed on a local server and I'm launching the application on a client, on the same domain.

I suspect it's an Oracle connection issue (maybe something to do with listener or tns), as when we open the application and it's pointing to a SQL database, it opens immediately.

I tried the below settings for the listner but it didn't help.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE) 
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

Any ideas as to why it takes so long, or what I can try to get it to connect and open quicker?

Thanks

Comment: Does it have the same delay if you connect with sql*plus from the same machine, or is it only VB?

Comment: From (patchy) memory ..... Oracle DB server started from 11g to lookup IP addresses for incoming coonections, and used DNS to resolve them. If you have no internet or no DNS accessible by the Oracle server you get this step timing out, which is why you see the 30 sec delay. Check the local network config on the ORacle server,

Comment: @kfinity Actually, when I did a tnsping it's also taking 20 seconds.

Comment: @TenG we have internet access on my local PC (client) and the server. The Oracle server is setup for DNS, as in it has it's own server name, and as far as I'm aware all Oracle file/connections all use this server name, rather than the IP address.

Comment: With your note about tnsping being affected by a 20 sec delay also points towards a issue with DNS. Usually a DNS server referenced in resolve.conf is down or inaccessible.I cannot remember how to disable this lookup. Other key files were /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/netsvc.conf and checking if the listner is binding to IPV6 or IPV4 address (V4 would be easier I suggest). Without having a level 16  client trace not much more I can say.

Comment: Woah, thanks guys. I looked into the DNS side of things. I went to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts on the server and client. Setting the server ip and name on the server made no difference. However, changing it on my client PC, tnsping returned in 10ms :) 

One follow up question - how would I go about changing this on all client PCs? Is it a manual job for each user on each PC to change their host file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked to be a DNS issue, thanks to @kfinity and @TenH.

What I did exactly to fix this was below:

- Went to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts on my client.
- Inserted my server name and server IP in here and saved.

Voila. TNSping came back in 10ms, opposed to 22000ms :)

Answer (score 0):

Listener log file!
When it passes 4 Gig, everything slows to a crawl. Timeouts are also a sign of this. We have Oracle 11g. Listener log is here-->
oracle\diag\tnslsnr<hostname>\listener\trace